# is this fine for multiple constructors?

Tags: python

I have been learning some basics of OOP in Python and I found that it does not allow multiple constructors on it. However, I have tried the following code:

```
class Whatever:

    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def Whatever(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

and when I execute it, this works just as multiple constructors:

```
c=Whatever()
print c.x,c.y
0,0
d=Whatever(1,2)
print d.x,d.y
1,2
```

is this fine to build multiple constructors in Python?

Comment: This will work as well even if you remove `Whatever` method.

Comment: I suppose he obvious question is: why?  Why do you need multiple constructors?  One of the reasons people ask for this is because they come from another language, like C++, where this practice is common.  Usually the requirements can be met by using sensible default parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Your second "constructor" is actually never called. The `__init__` function is being called when you call `Whatever` both with and without arguments; calling `Whatever(1,2)` simply calls `__init__` with `x=1` and `y=2`.

The `Whatever` function you added will not behave the way you want if you *do* call it, because it's an instance method; you'd need to already have a `Whatever` instance created to call it. You want a `classmethod` instead:

```
class Whatever(object):

    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    @classmethod
    def Whatever(cls,x,y):
        return cls(x,y)

d = Whatever.Whatever(1, 2)
```

But this is really unnecessary, since `__init__` covers both ways you want to initialize your class.